# cartopy *whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cartopy

I am running Python 3.11.3 on VSCode Studio.
But I want to install Cartopy, and it's not working. The code is given below.

```
C:\Users\HomePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311>pip install 
C:\Users\HomePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Cartopy-0.20.2-cp310-cp310-win32.whl
```

The error is this:

```
ERROR: Cartopy-0.20.2-cp310-cp310-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Please advise on how to resolve this matter.

Comment: thats win32 ... presumably you are using win64 python ... it also looks like its supporting 3.10 and you are trying to install into 3.11

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I tried win64 it didn't work as well.

Comment: this wheel is not working
      Cartopy-0.20.2-pp38-pypy38_pp73-win_amd64.whl

Comment: that one is for python3.8 ... not for 3.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The easiest way to install Cartopy is by using [Conda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html). If conda is already installed, installation is as easy as:
>
> ```
> conda install -c conda-forge cartopy
> ```

[More installation methods of `Cartopy`](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/installing.html#installation)

[Conda in the vscode official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_conda-environments)